# POM.xml dependencies error

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have a error while configure the Hibernate project.there are some dependency not resolve.

**Error 1:--**

```
     ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2 from
     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
 reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original
 error: Could not transfer artifact javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2 from/to central 
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed 
immediately
```

**Error 2**

```
Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.2.GA
```

on this error I have tried with other question's answer on SO.but not getting satisfactory result.

**Error 3**

```
org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, 
 org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration)
```

Comment: Error 2 isn't the source of the error but a symptom. Look through the output to see why the artifact is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that you have used a dependency which does not exist to be more accurate the [version does not exist](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22javax.servlet%22%20AND%20a%3a%22jstl%22).

The message gives you the hint simply to delete the path from your local repository. The location in your local repository is `$HOME/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/` and there you will find a directory which only contains property files but no jar file. This directory can be deleted.

Apart from that you have to change your dependency version to one of the existing ones like 1.1.1 or 1.2.

Comment: thanks! but error 2 not resolved.

Comment: @Dev It would be helpful if you could post the full error output, cause without context it's sometimes hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: @khmarbaise http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.3.2.GA/hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.GA.pom

Comment: @khmarbaise http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-entitymanager%7C3.3.2.GA%7Cpom

Comment: @MariuszS Dam seen my failure.

Answer (score 2):

### Error 2

> > Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.2.GA

This is impossible, because [hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.GA.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.3.2.GA/hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.GA.jar) already is on Maven Central;

Maybe your internet connection was down or something like this. Please provide more information.